# &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; out of nowhere

Tags: posts, single, code

Something is inserting four non-breaking spaces into my single.php code, but I can't find the cause at all.

I have already tried to disable all plugins and restore the theme's initial settings.

Link: https://fredericobt.com/wp-fastest-cache-melhor-configuracao/

[image: Four non-breaking spaces]
It is not a problem of the theme because it does not occur in the demo:

Link: https://demo.mekshq.com/typology/?p=182&single_cover=img

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there can be space characters before the `<?php` at the top of the file. Or space characters after a closing `?>` at the end of the file.

The closing `?>` is not needed in PHP files. But anything before the opening `<?php`, or after the not-needed `?>` closing  will get rendered on the page.